# Find all links by class with Selenium

Tags: html, powershell, selenium, xpath

On the web page there are a few articles. I need to get links to all articles.

I use Selenium and Powershell.

I do a search with:

```
FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(@class, 'without')]").getattribute("href")`
```

but only get a link to the first article.

How to get links to all the articles?

All links articles view:

```
<a class="without" href="http://articlelink.html"><h2>article</h2></a>
```

Comment: Use the plural form: `FindElementsByXPath`

Comment: Thank you! But now I get two identical links to the same element. It is possible that to avoid duplication?

Comment: I don't know about Selenium but you can deduplicate the list in PS: `sort -unique`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `Powershell` But Using `java with selenium` you can do this like below mentioned code.

I know it's not a proper answer to deal with, but below code will give you the `hint`, that how you should go with other language.

```
List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.className("without"));   // Using list web-element get all web-elements, whose classname name as "without"
System.out.println(links.size());             //total number of links on the page.

for(int i = 0;i<links.size();i++)           
{
    System.out.println(links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));   //Using for loop getting one by one links name.
    links.get(i).click();                         // click the link if you want to click
    Thread.sleep(2500);                          //wait for 2.5 seconds
}
```

Hope my above answer will help you.

Comment: .getText() will not necessarily return the URL.  Your code example looks fine to me except that I'd use .getAttribute("href") instead

Comment: @Bill, You are right, I have correct my answer as well. By the way thanks for your reply. :)

Comment: Does my explanation of code `helped` you? If it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.