# StaleElementReferenceException when trying to click an element

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm implementing a `Selenium` test using `Java`. But, my tests fail due to a `StaleElementReferenceException`.I am doing the following

```
driver.get(URL);
List<WebElement> Anchors = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[not(contains(@style,'display:none'))]/a"));

//same URL again

driver.get(URL);
Anchors.get(0).click();
```

When I try to click any element from the Anchors list I get an error.

Comment: When do you try to click it?

Comment: After i reopen the same URL

Comment: Do you mean after the second `driver.get(URL);`?

Comment: yes, forexample if i do Anchors.get(0).click() after the second driver.get(URL) statement;

Comment: Elements you've defined becomes stale once you refresh (reopen) page. You need to re-define your list of links after each `driver.get(URL)`. However instead of this I suggest you just to get list of references (`getAttribute('href')`)  of each anchor element and loop through it

Comment: Try this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571645/find-all-links-by-class-with-selenium/42574256#42574256

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time the DOM is changing or refreshing, even if you still in the same page, the driver "losses" the `WebElements` it previously located and you get `StaleElementReferenceException`. If you really need to use `driver.get(URL);` again before the click you need to relocate the list.